# Review of personal code

Tags: google-apps-script

I found this code and implemented it into my spreadsheet. My problem is that the code overwrites some data validation I had in my empty list. I wish to keep that drop down menu since I want the users to have it as easy as possible. I thought I could add the lines below (see text between **)

```
function onEdit(event) {
    // assumes source data in sheet named Masterlist
    // target sheet of move to named Actionlist
    // test column with yes/no is col 13 or M; 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "Masterliste" 
         && r.getColumn() == 13 && r.getValue() == "Ja") {
        var row = r.getRow();  
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();   
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Actionlist");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

        // **
        var cellrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(target);
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName("Dropdown").getRange('A16:B18'); //This is the range for the dropdown I want to hand over.

         var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
         cell.setDataValidation(rule);  //Include a data validation menu in each line automatically
         // **

         s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target); //This executes the copy order with the data provided before
    }
}
```

I know this might be easy for some of you but I have just started with google 4 months ago and it's driving me crazy. I am familiar to excel and VBA, but not to Java at all.
    Yes I did already do the codeacademy courses. They really didn't help me a lot. Sorry for my tone I am getting really annoyed by this. Thanks for your help. Enjoy the weekend!

Comment: So, the `copyTo(target)` overwrites the data validation set in the statement just above it?  Can you set the validation last?  After the values are copied?

Comment: Have you tried copying the contents only? Reference here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)

Comment: thakns for your answers so far. I'll post a test sheet so you guys know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an option to copyTo.  Here is what that looks like:

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target, {contentsOnly:true});
```

---

Alternatively you could use: `copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)

Comment: This site is a question and answer site, currently I can see you have a problem, but without a clear goal or question we cannot give you a proper answer.  Please try to describe what you are trying to do as clearly as possible.  Are you trying to copy values and not formatting?  Are you trying to copy formatting?  Are you trying to add new data validation to some cells?

Comment: Hey guys: My goal is to create a tracking list. Sort of a CAPA (Corrective And Preventive Action) tool but not really advanced.
[Link to testsheet][1]
Formating is not required. Just copy paste and creating the drop down options(though this is not a must so far. I just want to prevent users to enter the same expressions, so the conditional formating works.

  [1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H-H6ZC0ivU8lcwAdcxdeMp43jryEIAeQAwMHNJYTg4U